# Dynamic 301 redirects of Sub-domain to main domain in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

How I can redirect all sub domains for the main domain in Nginx?

aaa.domain1.com -> domain1.com

www.domain2.com -> domain2.com

bbb.domain3.com -> domain3.com

```
server_name *.domain1.com *.domain2.com *.domain3.com *.domain4.com;
return 301 http://XXX$request_uri;
```

Comment: The solution is to use [regular expression server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) to capture the part of the domain you need in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
server {
    listen       ....;
    server_name  ~^.*\.?(?<domain>.+\.com)$;
    return       301 http://$domain$request_uri;
}
```

This will check for any server name which has:

- one or more subdomains or not (`^.*\.?`)
- followed by an arbitrary *main-domain*.com (`(?<domain>.+\.com)$`)

The `?<domain>` saves the *main-domain*.com in a variable, so you can use it in the return statement (domain1.com, domain2.com, etc. in your case).

**Note:** I did not test this but hopefully you can see the concept in this example.

Comment: Thank you, but I must have static server names in server_name to avoid problems with other server names on same server.

Comment: ok, but then you can just replace the arbitrary domain (`.+\.com`) with your static domains (like `(domain1.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com)` in the regex expression